# incompatible types: a protoClass cannot be converted to MessageOrBuilder

Tags: java, android, gradle, protocol-buffers

I want to print a protobuf message to json. I do the following:

```
JsonFormat.Printer jsonPrinter = JsonFormat.printer();
StringBuilder toStore = new StringBuilder();
toStore.append("[");
toStore.append(jsonPrinter.print(pointRecord.build())); // point record is a builder of protoMessage.
```

I get the following error:

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
 /app/src/main/java/com/example/exampleapp/RecordsCollector.java:131: error: incompatible types: PointRecord cannot be converted to MessageOrBuilder
        toStore.append(jsonPrinter.print(pointRecord.build()));
                                                          ^
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

I think I need to build full protobuf and not only lite protobuf. However, I don't know how to do it. 
I put here a part of the gradle.build file of the application:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
...
protobuf { 
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
    }
    plugins {
       javalite {
           artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
       }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                remove java
            }
            task.plugins {
                javalite { }
            }
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
     })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0' 
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.0.0' 
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Did you received any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following snippet to compile full protobuf version:

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {}
            }
        }
     }
}
…


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.5.0'
}
```